# How to calculate Kafka consumer processing time in Spring Webflux and Micrometer

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-webflux, reactive, flux, micrometer

I am new to reactive programming and have written a kafka consumer in Spring Webflux to consume events, do processing on it and handles success and failure scenarios. I want to understand how can I calculate metrics of time taken to process each event (both success and failures) using micrometer. I know we can use Timer interface of Micrometer to calculate processing time like this-

```
Timer timer = Timer.builder("kafka.consumer.time")
                    .tag("eventType", "Event A")
                    .register(meterRegistry);
    timer.record(Duration.ofMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - inTime));
```

where inTime- the time event processing starts.

But I am not able to figure out how should I use "inTime" in reactive programming scenario given its a stream of events and it will be handling multiple events at a time.

```
 @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void consume() {
    kafkaReceiver
            .receive()
            .concatMap(res -> kafkaHelper.process(res)
                    .doOnError(error -> {
                        log.error("Error occurred);
                    }).retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(9)).jitter(0.5))
                    .onErrorResume(error -> {
                        log.error("Retry exhausted);
                        return Mono.empty();
                    })
                    .doOnSuccess(val -> {
                        res.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
                    })).subscribe();

}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you can look into around this problem space:

1. [Reactor has micrometer support for publishers](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_publisher_metrics)
   so you can name your `Flux` and request recording metrics like this:

```java
receive()
    .name("kafka.events") 
    .metrics() 
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .subscribe();
```

2. You should never measure elapsed time like that (`System.currentTimeMillis()`), [here's why](https://develotters.com/posts/how-not-to-measure-elapsed-time/)
3. Micrometer has [support for Kafka](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka) that can provide a bunch of additional metrics directly from the Kafka client, also if you happen to use spring-kafka, you can get additional things on top of these